# How can I create a oauth (REST) API ( like twitter or foursquare ) using django?

Tags: django, api, rest, oauth-2.0

I would like to create an oauth (REST) API the same way Twitter or Foursquare does.

I found this website http://djangopackages.com/ which is really great and has several packages but I would like some opinions on which is the best package, etc...

I would like, for example, let people to allow permission to 3rd party apps to access their data (Using API Keys, etc...)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django is a wonderful web framework. It helpes you in many ways making rich web applications. It helps you starting in form handling and ending in templating.

However in your case if your intension is just to make an awesome API such as of Twitter or Foursquare, you have to ask yourself if you need all this help Django provides. For example, are you ever going to use any templates in the API or process a for submittions. The answer is probably not...

So if you need a very flexible framework to developer an API, I would highly recommend to take a look into [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/). It is very similar to Django, however does not have all this extra cludder which is not necessary for an API.

However if your application needs both a rich user interface and an API or you just want to use Django, like Ulusses suggested, then I think [TastyPie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) is for you. It is a great library where you can have a running API in no time. I use it all the time and it is very flexible. [ReadTheDocs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/who_uses.html) uses tastypie.

Another API lib is [piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home). I haven't used it so can't judge if its better or worse then tastypie. Bitbucket however uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie or https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home.

You can achieve what you want with both, check out on the documentation the one that suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

I use Django REST framework. It is awesome.

Answer (score -1):

Piston is dead. Tastypie is awesone, but works with Django only. There are pros and cons with Django as well as Pyramid. If you need great ORM, sqlalchemy is only one, and there is no good example of using it with Django, so in this case you have Flask, Bottle or Pyramid. Django ORM is really not at that par.
If you choose Pyramid, you will have to write a lot of things, and the framework is just skinned boneless cat. You need to assemble and configure every block, seems frustrating to many including me.